# Suppress "No Disk Error" programatically using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage

Tags: c#, dvd

I have a small application, it reads a DVD Rom Disk, and scans for bad sectors, or un-readable areas on the disk.

My small app is designed to tell the user where to look, to identify damage/scratches to the surface.

I have been getting the dreded error: No Disk Error

[image]

I would like to know, if anyone can suggest, the declaration:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("???", "???")]
```

could be used to suppress this error, and if so, how I may find out how to use this better?

Comment: Code analysis is a compile-time code-quality feature, and is nothing to do with runtime errors.

Comment: The SuppressMessageAttribute is only used for analysis of the code and has no effect for the compiled program.

Comment: Ok thank you, I misunderstood the remarks (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Thanks